# where dch (from devscripts) take a string for version bump?

Tags: continuous-integration, deb, dpkg

Debian's devscripts suite has dch tool which allow to add new version to debian/changelog file.

When I add new version I make this:

```
package (1.0.2-1myname1-ubuntu0) UNRELEASED; urgency=medium

 *
 -- signature and date

package (1.0.2-1myname1) unstable; urgency=medium

  * old changes

-- signature and date
```

If version ends on 'ubuntu' it bumped properly (ubuntu1, ubuntu2, etc), and when I use my own suite, it just append 'ubuntu'.

Where dch take sting 'ubuntu' to add to version?

Comment: Which command line parameters did you use with the `dch` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is coming from the `dpkg-vendor` command. You can control it at least with the `DEB_VENDOR` environment variable, via the `DEBCHANGE_VENDOR` devscripts configuration option or the `dch`/`debchange` command-line `--vendor` option.

For more information please check the respective man pages.